# Limit the array of drugs in openFDA

Tags: openfda

Hello I am messing around with openFDA and was wondering if its possible to search for a medicinal product and only return objects with one drug in the array.

For example when you search for a drug, some patients have multiple drugs in the array. Some have up to 30!

[image]

Is it possible to search for patients who only have 1 object in the drug array?

This is what I am using to search for the medicinal product

`search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct`

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!